# Solve the equation $z^3=\sqrt3 +i$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve the equation:
$$z^3=\sqrt3 +i,$$ where $z$ is a complex number.

I have already found that $$ \sqrt3+i=2(\cos(\pi/6)+i \sin(\pi/6))$$

How can I solve the equation above?
Thank you very much.

Comment: It's always a good idea to write $z=re^{i\theta}$. What is then $z^3$?

Comment: Do I have to write z as x+yi?

Comment: In the end, yes. But if you set $z=re^{i\theta}$ then you have the equation
$$
z^3 = r^3 e^{i 3\theta} = r^3 (\cos{3\theta} + i \sin{3\theta}) = 2 \left( \cos{\frac{\pi}{6}} + i \sin{\frac{\pi}{6}} \right)
$$
This should be pretty straightforward to solve already.

Comment: Another hint: You will have to consider the equation
$$
\sin{3\theta} = \sin{\frac{\pi}{6}}
$$
How many solutions does this have in general? Furthermore, how many solutions does this have when we restrict $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$ ?

Comment: If you can solve $w^3=1$, then you can solve yours.

Comment: @MattiP. ... not "always".  There may be a certain point in someone's education where they learn $\cos(\theta) + i \sin (\theta)$ but do not yet have the knowledge to understand the complex exponential function.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong but I believe you are not familiar with the form $z=re^{i\theta}$.

Are you familiar with $cis$? Basically, $cis\theta=cos\theta+i*sin\theta$.

Notice that $z^3=\sqrt3+i=2cis\frac{\pi}{6}+2\pi k$

That means that $z=2^\frac{1}{3}cis\frac{\pi}{18}+\frac{2}{3}\pi k$

Therefore $z=2^\frac{1}{3}cis\frac{\pi}{18},2^\frac{1}{3}cis\frac{13\pi}{18},2^\frac{1}{3}cis\frac{25\pi}{18}$ are all solutions.

Answer (score 0):

One cube root of $2\exp\frac{i\pi}{6}$ is $\sqrt[3]{2}\exp\frac{i\pi}{18}$. Multiplying by $\exp\frac{2i\pi}{3}$ gives another, $\sqrt[3]{2}\exp\frac{13i\pi}{18}$. We multiply by $\exp\frac{2i\pi}{3}$ again to get the final cube root, $\sqrt[3]{2}\exp\frac{25i\pi}{18}$.

Answer (score 0):

v$$z^3=2 e^{i\pi/6} =2 e^{i(2n+1/6)\pi} \implies z=(2)^{1/3} e^{i(2n+1/6)\pi}, n=0,1,2.$$ So there three roots three roots $(n-0,1,2 <3)$: $$ 2^{1/3} e^{i\pi/6},~ 2^{1/3} e^{13 i\pi/18}, 
~2^{1/3} e^{25i\pi/18}$$

Comment: How We reached the conclusion that n=0,1,2?

Comment: @Vasilis Here the power if z is 3, so three roots and hence $n=0,1,2 <3$